# How to make commad as variable in shell scrpit

Tags: scripts

I wrote a script to check file exit then check if that file have given line, and finally print that line, here is this

```
#!user/bin/bash
echo "$1 $2"
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    if [ "$(wc -l "$1")" -ge 1 ]; then
        sed -n "1p" "$1"
    fi
fi
```

But it return error like `Illegal number: 3 /home/k/Documents/text.txt`

My question is, how to make `wc -l "$1"` as a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output of `wc -l file` includes the filename as well as the count.

```
$ wc -l file
8 file
```

As a workaround, you can redirect the file content to `wc -l` via the shell's standard input stream:

```
$ wc -l < file
8
```

So

```
if [ "$(wc -l < "$1")" -ge 1 ]; then
    sed -n "1p" "$1"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks , it work !!

Answer (score 1):

Only keep the first field in the `wc` output.  Awk is my favorite tool for that:

```
wc -l "$1" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

To capture this in a variable:

```
COUNT="$(wc -l "$1" | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer